# How to deal with package dependency conflict?

Tags: python

## Problem

Trying to use DBT 1.x which is used organisation-wide. We also need to use Flask 2.x but they have conflict.

```
flask 2.1.2 depends on Jinja2>=3.0
dbt-core 1.2.1 depends on Jinja2==2.11.3
```

## Question

What is the normal/best way to deal with such situation where widely used Python packages have dependency conflict?

Comment: How about using virtual environments?

Comment: In addition to @funnydman: Do you need to use both modules in the _same_ codebase/project?